# GUI (Windows) for portable Git for a beginner

Tags: windows-7, git, portable, dropbox

Background:

- I'm a beginner to Git.
- I intend to use it to store a small repository on Dropbox on my PC.
- I have downloaded portable Git (I prefer using portable software when possible).

Would love your recos on which GUI (Windows 7) I should try that will play well with the portable version of Git.

Comment: What do you mean by “portable”?

Comment: A word of warning I use Box and have found that it is totally unsuitable for repository storage due to a pile of file/directory naming restrictions that are not well advertised, including not syncing files/directories that start with . which lets git out obviously. It is worth checking if there might be the same restrictions on Dropbox. For git I would always recommend using GitHub to host the repository.

Comment: @BasilBourque The "thumbdrive version" that doesn't need to be installed. So it doesn't affect the registry. Google for it, you'll find it. It's an official release.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Fair warning. I might use bitbucket instead because they have free private repositories. GitHub free will make my potentially billion dollar idea (cough) public.

Comment: FYI: Download page for [*Git for Windows Portable ("thumbdrive edition")*](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Comment: @BasilBourque Notice how that page starts an automatic download? That's why I didn't link it originally :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possibilities that might get you started:

1. The built in git GUI, in your portable apps console change directory to an existing git repository, (checked out with `git clone` or created with `git init`), and simply type `git gui` to get a rather basic but usable git GUI.
2. Check for a portable IDE that supports your language and has a git client plug-in or built in, some possibilities include:

   - [Atom (Portable)](http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#portable-mode) with [git-gui](https://atom.io/packages/git-gui) Extension. *Good for many languages*
   - [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) has limited git integration and can be installed portable. *Good for Python*
   - [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) is available in portable editions and has [egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

Comment: I started playing around with the built-in GUI (git-gui), and found it adequate for my needs. The massive amount of new Git jargon is going to take some getting used to though!

Comment: If you have a free choice of version control software I would take a look at Mercurial, (hg/TortoiseHg), as it is much more user friendly. (It is portable as well).